# Should the "ergonomics" tag be synonymized with the "physical" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I realize they are not exactly the same, and it would not pay all the due respect to the field of Ergonomics, but in the context of USXE in the year 2013, it seems to be a useful synonym.

What do you think?

p.s. it this the right way to propose tags synonyms here?

Answer (score 4):

There's software ergonomics too; in fact using the broadest definition of ergonomics, most everything asked on the site could be considered ergonomics. There's definitely non-physical ergonomics questions: [What are the must have elements of a web(site) ergonomics analysis?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/what-are-the-must-have-elements-of-a-website-ergonomics-analysis)

[ergonomics](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) might need to be defined more explicitly for our purposes or removed entirely as being overly broad, but I think think it's quite a synonym for [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical). I might merge most of the existing ergo questions into physical if we decide we don't want the tag (most asked ARE about physical things) but I don't think they should be considered defacto synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

OK, firstly, yes, this is a suitable place to propose tab synonyms. You could also propose them directly from the https://ux.stackexchange.com/admin/create-tag-synonym page, but posting in Meta is useful as it's possible more people will see it (we don't get many synonyms on UX.SE so people don't tend to go and review the existing suggestions)

There's more info on synonyms on the main Meta.StackOverflow site:  [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

### Anyway, onto your main question:

I don't think that ergonomics and physical are a 1:1 match, so don't really fit with being synonymed in my opinion. Yes, many questions tagged [ergonomics](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) are likely to also be tagged [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) but I don't think it works the other way around.

Not every physical question revolves around the *ergonomics* of said physical item; it could be concerned with the visual / symbolic aspects of the item, the audio noises made etc. Tagging for ergonomics would (in my opinion) only be done if it's an object you physically interact with, such as a door *handle*, but not for questions about more general uses of the object, such as the whole door itself.

Comment: The layout of a building would be an example of a physical thing about user experience questions could reasonably be asked, but I don't think ergonomics covers such things